# add video in website

Tags: asp.net, video, embed

If i use this code i don't see anything in firefox but well in chrome and explorer.
Anyone a idea to resolve this?

```
<embed id='embed1' runat="server" name='mediaPlayer' type='application/x-mplayer2'  
     pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'  displaysize='4'  
     autosize='-1' bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols='true' showtracker='-1' showdisplay='0'  
     showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width='500' height='405'  designtimesp='5311'   
    loop='false' src="movie.mp4" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: `type="application/x-ms-wmp"`

this supports .wmv, .wma, etc. (all windows formats)

and .mp4 is controversial due to copyright issue..

Note: Yes you need to install plug-in in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Media Player not working in firefox](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/eb75af4a-2594-4d46-8198-c311bb0deae8/)

Also:

In order to make Firefox able to render Media Player content, you need Windows Media Plugin in Firefox:

Download the Windows Media Player Firefox Plugin(http://port25.technet.com/pages/windows-media-player-firefox-plugin-download.aspx)